# How malware spreads nowadays

Tags: windows, malware

How malware nowadays spreads? For example, I have a Windows computer infected with some kind of malware (someone ran malicious executable on the computer when nobody was looking at it) and it can spread to other computers in, for example, local network. I think spreading by USB isn't the right or actual way nowadays.

Comment: This seems a bit broad as 'malware' can encompass so many things and 'spreading' doesnt specify the actual direction of the spread (within one computer, local network, global network, etc). I think you need to refine your question some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attack vectors are the same now as they have always been:

- executable
- email
- browser
- remote service exploit

As for executables, USB, downloads, cloud/network/remote file share, email attachments are all valid sources for people to click on something they shouldn't.